# Measuring level of uncorrelation from correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, covariance-matrix, cross-correlation

This question might not be completely well defined mathematically, but if so I am hoping that people can help point me in the right direction, since this is not a part of mathematics I have ever had much experience with.

Suppose I have a correlation matrix $C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & c_{12} & c_{13} \\ c_{21} & 1 & c_{23} \\ c_{31} & c_{32} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ associated with 3 variables.
I would like to get a measure of the level of "independence" or uncorrelatedness of each of these variables so essentially the part of each variable that is not correlated to any of the other variables. I am not entirely sure such a measure is even well defined?

Assuming that there is some measure of independence, how would I measure it? and is it derivable from the correlation matrix? or do I need additional information, like the generating time series?

I have been looking for any litterature on this, but have yet to find anything to get started with.

Comment: The *eigenvalues* of the correlation matrix tell the entire story.   They are three non-negative numbers, not a single number.  Any measure that might be relevant will be a function of those eigenvalues, such as their maximum, minimum, ratio of the range, or product.  (Their sum will always be $3,$ fwiw, so there's really just two "degrees of freedom" among these three numbers.)  The relevant part of mathematics is called *linear algebra.*  There are probably around $10^4$ textbooks devoted to that subject (I kid you not), dating back over 200 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that if you take the inverse of the correlation matrix, then take the reciprocal of the diagonal elements of the inverse, the result is one minus the $R^2$ values from the regression models of each variable regressed on all the others.  This is a quick way to compute the tolerances mentioned by @Christian Geiser.

For example, one minus the 1st element of the reciprocal of the diagonal of the inverse is the $R^2$ value for a regression using the first variable as $y$ and the remaining variables as $x$.  If this is close to 1 (close to 0 if you don't subtract from 1, the tolerance), then that indicates that variable is fairly redundant, the other variables contain most of the same information, close to 1 means more independent/not redundant.

A quick example in R:

```
> library(MASS)
> 
> x <- mvrnorm(100, mu=rep(0,3), Sigma=rbind(c(1,0.8,0.5),
+                                            c(0.8,1,0.7),
+                                            c(0.5,0.7,1)))
> c.x <- cor(x)
> c.x
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.8363891 0.5081135
[2,] 0.8363891 1.0000000 0.6805727
[3,] 0.5081135 0.6805727 1.0000000
> rbind(1-1/diag(solve(c.x)),
+       c(
+         summary(lm(x[,1]~x[,-1]))$r.squared,
+         summary(lm(x[,2]~x[,-2]))$r.squared,
+         summary(lm(x[,3]~x[,-3]))$r.squared
+         )
+     )
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.7065034 0.7876103 0.4756086
[2,] 0.7065034 0.7876103 0.4756086
>
```

Remember that the $R^2$ value can be interpreted as the proportion of the variation in the response variable that is explained by the regression, or variation in the other variables.

This is a quick set of values that will give a reasonable measure of "independence" for each variable in the set with a meaningful interpretation.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the tolerance statistic is something that could be helpful for you. It is defined as 1 - R^2 for a given variable, where R^2 is calculated based on a linear regression of that variable on all other variables. The tolerance statistic is available as a measure of collinearity in regression in software programs such as SPSS. See, for example:

https://www.statisticshowto.com/tolerance-level-statistics/